# Recursion with case expression Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider the following code, where the function `sumFood` takes a
list `xs` of `Food` and returns a tuple of integers. In this tuple, the first integer represents the number of fruits included in `xs` and the second integer the number of vegetables.

```
module Apples where

data Food = Apple | Orange | Carrot | Potato  deriving(Show)

sumFood :: [Food] -> (Int, Int)

 sumFood (x:xs) = let v=0
                      f=0  in if ((length xs)-1) > 0  then
    case x of  Apple -> (f + 1, v)
               Orange -> (f + 1, v)
               Carrot -> (f, v + 1)
               Potato -> (f, v + 1)
                                 else sumFood xs
```

But if I typed `sumFood [Apple , Orange]` or `[Apple, Apple]` it will return (0,0) and the answer should be (2,0).

The implementation has to use a case expression.

Maybe a Hint would be useful.

Comment: your implementation only matches on lists with exactly one element... have a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion

Comment: I know that is why I asked here  I know about recursion and I tried to use it   but  with case  expression !!! it's harder

Comment: Are you just asking how to pattern match a list? That has nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: my question is how to get to the result that if I typed [Apple , Orange , Apple ] =>I will get (3,0) I think that I need recursion I don't know !!!

Comment: So.. in every step of recursion you will have a list with one element less... and eventually an empty list. You best take that into consideration. Besides in `case` you will check the current element not a list, like `case x of Apple -> ...` and so on would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Redu I tried it but it returns (0,0) I know there is mistake in the implementation  but I don't know where !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually got most of the right bits and pieces, but in the wrong order - and you forgot to do anything with the result of the recursion.

You can substitute the values of `f` and `v` and see what's happening:

```
sumFood (x:xs) = let v = 0
                     f = 0  in 
    if ((length xs)-1) > 0  then
        case x of  Apple -> (f + 1, v)
                   Orange -> (f + 1, v)
                   Carrot -> (f, v + 1)
                   Potato -> (f, v + 1)
    else sumFood xs
```

becomes

```
sumFood (x:xs) = 
    if ((length xs)-1) > 0  then
        case x of  Apple -> (0 + 1, 0)
                   Orange -> (0 + 1, 0)
                   Carrot -> (0, 0 + 1)
                   Potato -> (0, 0 + 1)
    else sumFood xs
```

Now, `((length xs)-1) > 0` is `length xs > 1`, which means `length (x:xs) > 2`, so in practice you have

- If the list has more than two elements, the result is either `(1,0)` or `(0,1)`.
- Otherwise, recurse.

Now it's (hopefully) obvious that the result can only ever be `(1,0)` or `(0,1)` - unless the input has fewer than three elements, in which case you will eventually encounter a pattern-matching failure.

The main problem is that you never use the result of the recursion, so the result is always that of your base case.

First off, a useful rule of thumb is to never use `length`; use pattern matching on the list structure.

Start with the base case: the empty list contains neither fruit nor vegetable.

```
sumFood [] = (0,0)
```

Next, you need to get the result from the recursion, and then add one to the appropriate element of the result:

```
sumFood (x:xs) = let (f, v) = sumFood xs 
                 in
                    case x of Apple -> (f + 1, v)
                   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Bifunctor` instance of `(,)` makes this easy; it lets you use `first` and `second` to apply `(+1)` to the appropriate element of a tuple, which allows you to simply fold the list into a tuple.

```
import Data.Bifunctor

sumFood :: [Food] -> (Int, Int)
sumFood = foldr foo (0,0)
  where foo Apple = first (+1)
        foo Orange = first (+1)
        foo Carrot = second (+1)
        foo Potato = second (+1)
```

If you are required to use a `case` expression, note that multiple equations to define a function are just syntactic sugar for one:

```
sumFood :: [Food] -> (Int, Int)
sumFood = foldr foo (0,0)
  where foo food = case food of
                     Apple -> first (+1)
                     Orange -> first (+1)
                     Carrot -> second (+1)
                     Potato -> second (+1)
```

If you also aren't allowed to use `Bifunctor`, it's easy enough to implement yourself on the fly:

```
sumFood :: [Food] -> (Int, Int)
sumFood = foldr foo (0,0)
  where foo food = case food of
                     Apple -> \(f,v) -> (f+1,v)
                     Orange -> \(f,v) -> (f+1,v)
                     Carrot -> \(f,v) -> (f,v+1)
                     Potato -> \(f,v) -> (f,v+1)
```